# getUserMedia use audio only will be closed by itself in few seconds on mac chrome

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome, webrtc, getusermedia

The same code bellow, you can run it in chrome console on both windows OS and Mac OS.

`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true})`

On my Mac, it will be closed in a few seconds.

On my Windows, it works fine.

In my project, there are no any code changed, it works fine in the past few months... but these days, it's broken on mac chrome...

See sample code here [Sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/zsney/L9k4crth/1/)

Steps:

1. Click on `show` button, you can get `undefined`
2. Click on `start` button.
3. After Media started, click `show` button, you can get a MediaStream object with `active: true`. And you can see the red circle on chrome tab.
4. Wait a few seconds(maybe 10s), you can see the red circle on chrome tab will missing, then click the `show` button, you can get a MediaStream object with `active: false`.

BTW, this issue is on `mac chrome`, `windows chrome` is correct.

==============chrome://media-internals/====================

After use `getUserMedia({audio: true})`, it shows an item in `input controllers`, then I open it as follow, but after a few seconds. this item disappeared.

```
channel_layout: STEREO
channels: 2
component_id: 5
component_type: 0
device_id: default
device_type: pcm_low_latency
effects: NO_EFFECTS
frames_per_buffer: 441
owner_id: 6976
render_process_id: 7664
sample_rate: 44100
status: started
web_contents_title: javascript - getUserMedia use audio only will be closed by itself in few seconds on mac chrome - Stack Overflow
```

Comment: `it will be closed` - what will be closed?

Comment: MediaStream will be stopped.

Comment: How do you know the `MediaStreamTrack`  has stopped capturing user media? Can you include the code that you have tried at Question? Have you file a [bug](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/), https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines?

Comment: 2 things, 1st is I will use `MediaStream` later in my project, I will got `null`, 2nd is the red circle on chrome tab which indicate whether the media is active or not, it will disappeared in few seconds after the media is active.

Comment: _"will use `MediaStream` later in my project"_ What do you mean by "later"? `MediaStream` represents live captured media. Can you include the full code and the steps necessary to reproduce the issue at Question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I can't repro on the same configuration. What does chrome://media-internals/ tells you about your "Audio"? You might also want to check chrome://webrtc-internals/ and finally, does this happens on other browsers or only chrome?

Comment: Thanks all, I applied a sample code on my post. please take a look...

Comment: Add the `chrome://media-internals` result, please take a look, thanks very much.

Comment: And what about other browsers? Firefox, Safari? Or even other apps using this device? Sounds very much like a problem with your mic, not with the browser.

Comment: thank you, I tested on my mac firefox, it's correct. I tried others mac chrome, also correct.. only my mac chrome... my mic should no problem. as firefox is OK.

Comment: not only my mac, here some other guys mac chrome got this issue,

Comment: Then file a bug report to chrome team.

Comment: Thanks so much, I upgrade my mac from 10.12.5 -> 10.12.6, chrome 61 -> 62. issue solved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, maybe the OS and chrome issue.

I upgrade mac os from `10.12.5 -> 10.12.6`, and chrome from `61 -> 62`, issue solved.